# S = { (a,b) be elements of Real Numbers| |a-b|<2 or |a-b|=2}. List three elements in S[4]?

Tags: relations

I know or at least correct me if I'm wrong two elements are {3,2}. How would I come to find another element?

Comment: What do you mean by S[4]

Comment: sorry it should just be [4]

Comment: What does it mean now?

Comment: where a in S is 4: |4-b|<2 or |4-b|=2

Comment: The class of $4$, $[4]$, consists of all numbers that are at distance $2$ of smaller from $4$. This is the closed interval $[2,6]$.